# $http angularjs

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, post, get

Привет! У меня есть апи с доступом к task'ам, нужно отправить get запрос и полученное вывести в li.
Вот запрос:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3001/get1')
    .success(function (result){
        console.log('success', result);
        $scope.tasksArr = result;
    })
    .error(function (result){
        console.log('error');
});
```

и есть список

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasksArr track by $index">
    {{task.text}}
</li>
```

Как правильно написать чтобы отобразилось?

Comment: А почему вы присваиваете после запроса данные свойству `$scope.books` вместо нужного `$scope.tasksArr`?

Comment: Да, забыл исправить)

Comment: Приведите также хотя бы часть результата вывода `console.log('success')`

Comment: ! Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: это вы уже на then заменили, тогда и логировать надо `result.data`

Comment: Object {error: null, success: Array[8]}

Answer (score 2):

Вы итерируете не тот массив(`tasksArr` вместо `books`):

```
<li ng-repeat="task in books track by $index">
    {{task.text}}
</li>
```

---

Также хочу отметить, что методы `.success`/`.error` являются устаревшими и их не рекомендуется использовать. Используйте `.then`:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3001/get1')
    .then(function (response){
        console.log(response.data); // {error: null, success: Array}
        $scope.books = response.data.success;
    })
    .catch(function (response){
       console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
    });
```

Рабочий пример

```js
(function(module){
  module.controller('Test', Test);
  
  Test.$inject = ['$http', '$scope'];
  
  function Test($http, $scope) {
    $http.get('http://httpbin.org/get', {params: {
      books: ['Book 1', 'Book 2', 'Book 3']
    }})
      .then(response => response.data.args.books)
      .then(books => $scope.books = books);
  }
})(angular.module('app', []));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Test as c">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">
      {{book}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, не вывод, а только наоборот дублировалось li>task in taskArr

Comment: @Alexey, я решительно не понимаю, что вы хотите сказать

Comment: http://oi66.tinypic.com/wt86mq.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `{{task.text}}` на просто `{{task}}`. Тогда вы хоть увидите, что у вас там

Comment: Теперь в нижней li отобразился весь массив объектов, первый li не убрался

Comment: А теперь? У тебя же свой формат ответа API

Comment: написал выше =)

Comment: Чего ты выше написал? `$scope.books = response.data.success` работает?

Comment: да, теперь отобразилось) Большое спасибо!